# How to restore a e2image image backup

Tags: backup, restore, ext4, lvm

I’ve created a image from my partition with the e2image tool like this:

```
e2image -rap /dev/sdb2 /backup/sdb2.e2image
```

The Partitions size is around 870GB, but it used only around 25GB. When I do a `ls -laht` to check it size, I get this:

```
-rw-------  1 root root 868G 31. Mär 10:36 sdb2.e2image
```

Then I check the size with `du`

```
25G /backup/sdb2.e2image
```

now I created a lvm:

```
LV        VG      Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert                                                    
arch_root vg_arch -wi-a-----  30.00g
```

Now i want to restore my old partition backup, to this lv, so I do:

```
e2image -rap /backup/sdb2.e2image /dev/mapper/vg_arch_root
```

But i always get an error during the restoring process:

```
e2image  no space left
```

What i'm doing wrong?